# Is multiple stage binary classification a good idea if you have very few positives?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, text-mining

The problem is the following: We have a set of, say 5000 documents, with a single binary label. Say that 4900 documents are negative and only 100 are positive.

I built a binary classifier while looking out that I use evaluation metrics and parameters suited for very uneven label distributions. Say that the results are not bad, but I want more.

So my idea is the following. What if you would decompose the classification problem into two stages. The first stage would filter out some documents that we are very sure have nothing to do with what we want to find, and in the second stage, you would be searching for what you really want.

To propose an example: say you have a large set of animals of which only a small portion are lions.

the original idea: construct a binary classifier to find the lions in the whole set.

the new idea: construct a binary classifier to find mammals in the whole set. Then construct a binary classifier to find lions in the set of mammals.

Do I have reason to believe that this would be a good idea. I mean is it at least worth trying out? Why? Why not?

For my specific case: I have a set of documents which at least have something to do with 'Marriage' or 'Divorce'. I want to find the documents in this set which describe exactly an event where two persons get married or divorced. My idea was to first find the events that at least indicate that a pair is near marriage or near divorce, and then search for documents that describe the exact action of marriage or divorce.

Comment: If your classes are unbalanced then you could try under/over sampling techniques

Answer (score 0):

If you can assign to a subsample of your documents a score (a number from 0 to 3, for example) that represents how *near* the couple is from marriage or divorce (where 3 is the actual divorce or marriage action), then you can use regression to try to predict this value on the whole set of 5000, and then filter out documents with low values to make your label distribution less skewed. Note, however, that keeping at least some documents with low score values may be important to make sure your classifier can generalize well.